# Google Maps Geocoding API license?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm looking everyone for where i get a api key to use Google Maps Geocoding API. Do i have to request a premier license to use this API? Or is there a low usage option somewhere?

Could someone point me in the correct direction please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's Map API V3 [does not use keys anymore](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html), so you don't need one.

> The Google Maps Javascript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. **Version 3 does not require an API key.** The V2 API will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps Javascript API.

Comment: I am not using the Javascript API, i am connecting to the Google Maps API JSON Web Services...

Comment: AFAIK, you still don't need an API key.

Comment: Ah, just saw that. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, we've just re-introduced keys for V3. However, they are optional. You get all sorts of cool statistics and dashboard for using a key.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a key through the [Google API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console).

However, using a key is completely optional.

Answer (score 0):

The site [says](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) that:

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)

If you don't think that will be enough, you can [sign up](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) for GMAPI for Business

Answer (score 0):

you can use **API KEY** from the google console

1> Go to the Google Maps Platform > Credentials page. Go to the Credentials page.

2> On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key. The API key created dialog displays your newly created API key.

3> Click Close.

While there is no maximum number of requests per day, the following usage limit is still in place for the Geocoding API:

50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing